# How to return mvc5 model via an ajax call which can then be iterated with foreach( mvc5model, function(key,value){}

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array, asp.net-mvc-5, deserialization

I need to return a model from mvc 5 controller via an ajax call, in a ObjectArray format which can be iterated as a key value pair.
I've tried stringify and 'toJSON' and @HTML.raw  and serializing the model on the controller side or using  cast to Json on controller side, but with no luck.
The viewModel passed back is an instantiated class with several properties.

Code:

```
public JsonResult FindPersonOn( long? IdNumber)
{
        // populate viewModel.Person
        // populate ViewModel.Designation

        //JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
                new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(driverViewModel);
        //return Json(sJSON);

        // return Json(viewModel)
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/DesignationPerson/FindPersonOn/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data)
    {
        //var obj = JSON.stringify(data);           
        //var obj = $.toJSON(data)

        var obj = data;
        $.each(obj, function (key, value)
        { 
            if (key == 'person')
            {
                // populate some html elements
               $('#LastName').val(value.LastName);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Exception;
    Unhandled exception at line 489, column 2 in http://localhost:60667/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected occurred

Data:

```
 {"crudAction":null,"DesignationUrl":null,"PersonID":1,"FkTitleID":1,"TitleCode":"Mr","TitleDetail":"Mister",
   "FirstName":"Neal","LastName":"Rogers","NickName":"Tinkerbell","SAIdNumber":"6512215026087","FkGenderID":1,
   "DateBirth":"\/Date(-127188000000)\/",
   "TitleLookup":[
               {"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":true,"Text":"Mister","Value":"1"},
               {"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Missus","Value":"2"},
              ],
"ClassificationLookup":[
              {"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Active","Value":"8"},
              {"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Suspended","Value":"9"}
              ],
"ID":null,
"FkEntityPersonID":null,
"FkRegionID":null,
"FkClassificationID":null,
"ClassificationDate":null,
"RegionDetail":null,
"ClassificationDetail":null}
```

Usually I pass the mode from an ActionResult with return View(model)
and in the view I serialize it with razor

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@{
    var javaScriptSearilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serializedPersonViewModel = javaScriptSearilizer.Serialize(Model);
}
```

and in the script on $(document).ready
I  get it into a local variable with serializedPersonViewModel = @Html.Raw(serializedPersonViewModel);

but in the ajax done or success, I can't get it working.

TIA

Comment: `return Json(viewModel)` will work, assuming there's no exceptions in the C# logic. To help you any further we need to know what the format of the response is, and any error message you receive

Comment: `dataType: "html"` makes no sense if you're trying to return JSON from the call. set `dataType: "json"` instead... That way, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON into a usable object / array variable and you can start using it immediately. And in the controller, simply use `return Json(...` and pass in your model object. MVC will automatically serialize it to JSON for you... no need for any manual serialisation.

Comment: I've updated the question with the exception, the data as received by the ajax call and using serialization and html.raw to convert it in script (which works fine)

Comment: json   yep not html. Missed it completely. thank you.

Comment: How do I mark it as answered then?

Comment: That was just a comment, so you can't. I could answer below, but TBH it's a pretty trivial typo, not sure it's of great benefit to humanity's future...there are already plenty of questions / tutorials etc on the net showing how to use MVC and jQuery AJAX in combination. This doesn't add any new knowledge. Probably better just to delete the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I spoke to soon, browser cached something.   the foreach still fails with Error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

Comment: Do some simple debugging: `success: function (data)
    { console.log(data);` ...what do you see in the log?

Comment: The 2 serialized objects are identical (copied each and pasted into notepad) or via the view as JSON or view as string). The first which serializes the same model as the view does, when the view loads and then using  @Html.Raw(serializedDriverViewModel);   so ,  .. not sure why. unless it's because I use the c# javaScriptSerializer to serialize the model before returning if from the controller. ?? but this one looks exactly the ame as the view's serilized model. maybe unseen formatting chars ?? will try just return(Json(viewModel), not return Json(serialized_view model).

Comment: "unless it's because I use the c# javaScriptSerializer to serialize the model" ...I already mentioned not to do that. If you're using that **as well as** `return Json()` then you'll be double-serializing the JSON

Comment: P.S. Assuming we're using the JSON sample at the end of your question, then the code is much simpler to achieve what you want in terms of populating the last name: https://jsfiddle.net/wzgp7019/

Comment: Yep, that was the issue all right. Thanks again.